# How to prevent certain kinds of formatting from getting pasted into WPF RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, formatting, richtextbox

I want to allow some simple formatting commands within a WPF RichTextBox but not others.

I've created a toolbar that allows users to apply bold or italics, and use bulleted or numbered lists. (Basically, I only want to support the formatting commands that would be appropriate for a blog or wiki.)

The problem is that users can perform cut and paste operations that insert text with foreground and background colors, among other kinds of disallowed formatting. This can lead to nasty usability issues like users pasting white text onto a white background.

Is there any way to turn these advanced formatting features off? If not, is there a way I can intercept the paste operation and strip out the formatting I don't want?

Answer (score 5):

You can intercept the paste operation like this:

```
    void AddPasteHandler()
    {
        DataObject.AddPastingHandler(richTextBox, new DataObjectPastingEventHandler(OnPaste));
    }

    void OnPaste(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.SourceDataObject.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Rtf, true)) return;
        var rtf = e.SourceDataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Rtf) as string;
        // Change e.SourceDataObject to strip non-basic formatting...
    }
```

and the messy part is keeping some but not all of the formatting.  The `rtf` variable will be a string in RTF format that you can use a third-party libary to parse, walk the tree using a DOM-like pattern, and emit new RTF with just text, bold and italics.  Then cram that back into `e.SourceDataObject` or a number of other options (see the docs below).

Here are `PastingHandler` docs:

- [DataObject.AddPastingHandler Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dataobject.addpastinghandler.aspx)

Here is one of many RTF parsers:

- [NRTFTree - A class library for RTF processing in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/nrtftree.aspx)

Comment: I was afraid I'd have to inspect and modify the RTF source. I can see this is going to get messy. Thanks, Rick. This is just what I needed to get started.

Comment: @alldayremix I don't think that will work here as the WPF RichTextBox is not based on the Windows rich text common control.

Comment: Oh wow, I completely missed that detail, my mistake. `PastingHandler` is the way to go then.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code if you wanted to strip all formatting from pasted content (Not what you asked, but may be usefull to someone):

```
    void OnPaste(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.SourceDataObject.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Rtf, true)) return;
        var rtf = e.SourceDataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Rtf) as string;

        FlowDocument document = new FlowDocument();
        document.SetValue(FlowDocument.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Left);

        TextRange content = new TextRange(document.ContentStart, document.ContentEnd);

        if (content.CanLoad(DataFormats.Rtf) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(rtf) == false)
        {
            // If so then load it with RTF
            byte[] valueArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rtf);
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(valueArray))
            {
                content.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
            }
        }

        DataObject d = new DataObject();
        d.SetData(DataFormats.Text, content.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\n"));
        e.DataObject = d;
    }
}
```

Comment: `e.SourceDataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Text)` also just returns the plain text from a RTF string.